# Next.js - how use postcss feature in *.module.css?

Tags: javascript, next.js, postcss

example:

```css
body{
  --color: #000;
  color: var(--color);
}
```

not compiled in *.module.css, but compiled in global scope css, so what should I do

Comment: `body` is not a pure selector. Wrap it in a class (`.root body {...}`) and then `add` it to `document.documentElement.classList` on component mount.

Comment: If this solution works, it should be an answer, not a comment, and should be accepted :) @brc-dd